# Deadline for site name?

Tags: discussion, essential-questions, site-name

I propose that we create a deadline for the voting on the site name so that we can move onto the logo/look-and-feel question.  Does anyone know when this is supposed to be completed?

Just to make the voting on this question clearer, let's put our proposed date as a header in the answer.

Comment: +1; I agree - Answer below proposes deadline

Comment: Incidentally, a valid answer would be "no deadline", in which, please use the same format and give a brief explanation for why.

Comment: Another potential answer would be something like "the first name that reaches 20 votes" (i.e. this doesn't have to be time-based).

Answer (score 7):

## August 23rd...

...and then a second round between best propositions, as proposed [on chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/chats/message/95398?offset=120).

Comment: +1 Sounds like a plan.

Comment: +1 I agree.....

Comment: Me too.........

Comment: I love the second round of voting idea. Why do we need to restrict it to "within 2 votes", though? Perhaps the top 2-3 choices?

Comment: @Aniko To fetch all proposals that have chances; I think that it is a fair algorithm.

Comment: I'll allow myself to mention that there is an idea to connect the second round with logo selection -- this issue can be discussed on chat http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170/stats .

Comment: +1  good idea...

Answer (score 2):

## August 23rd

I think that a deadline would be productive and is worth creating.  This date would give almost 2 weeks, and is on a Monday (which gives people an extra weekend).

Answer (score 0):

## X weeks before end of Public Beta

X must be such that the team at Stackoverflow has sufficient time to develop a logo and associated graphic elements to go with the new site name. I could be wrong but I am skeptical that we have the expertise to come up with a logo/graphics although we may have a sense of what looks good/acceptable etc.

Perhaps, someone at Stackoverflow can tell us what X is?

PS: By the way as long as we know what X is I do not see any reason to hurry the process.

Comment: According to Area51, "the site's progress will be evaluated in 69 days." http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33/statistical-analysis So it's ultimately a question of how much time we have to have set aside for the logo/design and any other question before the end of beta.

Comment: So....what's X?

Comment: Perhaps, one of the moderators can find out for us from Stackoverflow? Or perhaps, we can tag this 'feature request' (which is a bit dubious) to get their attention? I prefer the first approach.

Comment: This approach suggests that we should make a list of all issues that need to be addressed before re-evaluation and set all of those deadlines more or less at the same time.

Comment: Perhaps, a bit staggered to give ourselves some time between deadlines.

Comment: As I read your heading, X represents the number of weeks before the end of public beta: the public beta ends in 68 days, so what is X in your opinion?

Comment: X is whatever amount of time Stackoverflow needs to design a logo etc. I have no idea how much time they would require. A week? 3 days? You should ask Robert Cartaino. Note: If we need to accommodate a polling period to pick the 'best' one then we need to add X + Required polling time.

Comment: The logo is designed by us, not by stackoverflow. This is really  community driven.

Comment: @Shane I know that it is supposed to be community driven but I am not really sure we have the expertise to come up with a logo as we are not graphics experts. I could be wrong of course but that is my impression. That is the reason why I said that perhaps we can delegate the actual design to Stackoverflow and then vote on the ones we want as a community from several designs.

Comment: I see.  If you read #5 from http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/, you will see that it mentions the logo can be designed by the community or by the stackoverflow designers.  This is covered in this thread: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/269/what-should-our-logo-and-site-design-look-like.  I had previously seen on webapps that they were in the process of making their own: http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/245/site-logo-style-proposals.  But I guess it's an open question.

Comment: How about opening a thread to poll the see if someone is willing to come up with a logo as and when we finalize the site name? Or, perhaps, I am over analyzing the whole thing!

Comment: @Srikant: IMO, Rob's question should be enough for the discussion.  http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/269/what-should-our-logo-and-site-design-look-like  I am going to submit a design proposal myself, but you should also feel free to post an answer there proposing that SO contribute a design.  :)

Comment: Sure. Of course, if I like yours or some other proposed design I will vote for it instead of asking SO.